# JBoss 5 - Deciphering Stack Trace

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

In my deployment on JBoss 5.1.0GA with JavaEE-5 I have beans of the general form

```
public interface Foo {
   void baz ();
}

@Stateless
public class FooBean implements Foo {
   void baz() { // ...
   }
}
```

I have assumed that this is the same as if I have explicitly annotated the Foo interface with @Local.   From seeing a stack trace in the code I think that it is actually using a remote interface, whereas I want all of my beans to be local.

Do I need to explicitly annotate interfaces as Local or is there some default?  Finding documentation on this is proving challenging so any links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

(edit added suspicious stack trace)

The stack trace I'm getting looks like this.  The suspicious line is "$Proxy638".  FooBean is annotated as descrbied as above, and Client and Manager are both POJO's (e.g. completely unannotated with any Java EE related items).  This call is being processed by an Message-Driven bean if that is helpful.  I can see that the exception is one of mine ("My error message goes here!" is the message I want to real stack trace of).

```
2011-01-10 11:15:06,428 ERROR [org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.inflow.JmsServerSession](WorkManager(2)-11) Unexpected error delivering message delegator->JBossMessage[21211678385963013]:PERSISTENT, deliveryId=5
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: My error message goes here!
  at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:115)
  at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
  at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.invoke(RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.java:94)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
  at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:182)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:240)
  at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:188)
  at $Proxy638.generateWidget(Unknown Source)
  at com.foobar.managers.Client.writeBananaToStream(Client.java:456)
  at com.foobar.managers.Client.write(Client.java:123)
  at com.foobar.managers.Manager.persist(Manager.java:275)
  at com.foobar.FooBean.doSomething(FooBean.java:1243)
```

Note that I've had to anonymize the code so any mismatching things to do with class names are almost certainly typos!

Comment: http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/simple-stateless-example.html appears to confirm that the default is local, but I was hoping for an authorative source (e.g. something from JBoss or from the EJB specifications).

Comment: what part of stack trace makes you think it's remote?

Comment: I added more details of the problem together with the stack trace.

Comment: $Proxy is a proxy between your business logic and underlying ejb internals of JBoss. I'm not a big fan of jboss stacktraces, but usually remote call error logs are full of Object I/O streams, remote invocations, marshalling and such. No problem in your case :)

Comment: Is there anything at all I can do to get better stack traces?  The "My Error Message Exception" is thrown at various places within my code, but I just want to see where!

Comment: Write your own utility method that filters org.jboss.aop, and org.jboss.ejb etc from the stack trace? This is not really JBoss specific. Check the stack traces in e.g. Tomcat when your servlet is called with a few of your filters before that. You see a lot of Tomcat internal code being called before it reaches your code every time.

Comment: This isn't really about filtering out JBoss specific (or X specific) code.  The exception is thrown by my code, but my code doesn't appear in the stacktrace.  The method that is throwing inside Client.writeBananaToStream is my code so I would expect it to be in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a local call.

With JBoss AS, if you omit the @Local annotation you get local interface semantics. I'm not 100% sure whether this is spec compliant, so better define it explicitly by putting that annotation there.

The `$Proxy638` that you see is at the heart of how EJB and similar component models work. It's the reason why you can't use the new operator to create an EJB, but can only look one up via JNDI of have one injected via the @EJB or @Inject annotation.

You never get the object directly, but instead you get a proxy, also known as a stub. In EJB terms you are said to have a `Client view` on the actual bean. This proxy allows the EJB container to do its AOP magic, like starting a transaction transparently and committing or rollbacking it.

Comment: The object in question is one of mine though, so I'd expect to be able to get the stack trace from it?  The stack trace at the moment doesn't include details of where in my own code the exception was thrown from; that's what I'm trying to solve (rather than filtering out the JBoss noise).

Comment: My guess is that this is a basic Java thing that is unrelated to EJB: the exception you're after is wrapped by the *EJBTransactionRolledbackException* and you simply need to walk the exception chain by simply calling ``exception = exception.getCause()`` in a loop until exception is null.